# Lat Lng Search Along Line from Direction (Geographic North)

Tags: gps, point-of-interest, geodesic

Most of the lat lng searches are for POIs within a radius. How does one define POIs+(margin of error) that are along a (infinite) straight line (or geodesic or great sphere) defined by a north direction, from a certain lat lng?

From

```
Origin: (lat,lng) 
Direction: North (Degrees)
```

Determine

```
POIs along line defined by above boundaries, with a margin of error (+/- 50 m, given GPS inaccuracies)
```